# Windows Server 2008 Script to close share sessions

Tags: windows-server-2008

In the **Share and Storage Managment** console, you are able to close all session for a particular share by highlighting the share, clicking manage sessions, and closing your connections form there.

Is there a way to perform this same task via a script. We have an end user that is unable to eject removable media because there are open sessions on the share and this is the only way we have found to release the connections.

Ideally, providing the end user with a script that does this behind the scenes would be best.

Anyone have any suggestions?

-Brian

Comment: Why is an end user sharing removable media from their PC?

Comment: It is shared between two servers.

Answer (score 1):

**FOR ALL SHARES**

`net session \\computername /delete` (where computername is the name of the computer connected...which you can see via just `net session`)

or if you want to disconnect everyone:

`net session /delete`

**FOR A SINGLE SHARE VIA VBSCRIPT**

```
Set objConnection = GetObject("WinNT://SERVER/SHARE")
Set colSessions = objConnection.Sessions

For Each objSession in colSessions
    colSessions.Remove(objSession.Name)
Next
```

---

I'm not aware of a Powershell cmdlet that works on 2008 to close an SMB session, but maybe there is one.

Comment: But won't that delete all sessions to all shares on that particular machine? I just want to close sessions on one particular share.

Comment: updated the answer